# MongoDB - query for a nested item inside a collection

Tags: mongodb, nested

i have a mongodb collection "result" with data like

```
{ "_id" : { 
           "user" : "Howard", 
           "friend" : "Sita" 
           }, 
"value" : {
          "mutualFriend" :[ "Hanks", "Bikash", "Shyam", "Bakshi" ] 
          } 
}

{ "_id" : {
          "user" : "Shiva", 
          "friend" : "Tom" 
          }, 
  "value" : { 
          "friendList" :[ "Hanks", " Tom", " Karma", " Hari", " Dinesh" ] 
            }
}

{ "_id" : { 
         "user" : "Hari", 
         "friend" : "Shiva" 
          }, 
 "value" : { 
          "mutualFriend" :[ "Tom", "Karma", "Dinesh" ] 
           } 
 }
```

Now, here i want to query whole Document having `value.mutualFriend`. how can i get the result?

**Expected Output**

```
{ "_id" : { 
           "user" : "Howard", 
           "friend" : "Sita" 
           }, 
"value" : {
          "mutualFriend" :[ "Hanks", "Bikash", "Shyam", "Bakshi" ] 
          } 
}
{ "_id" : { 
         "user" : "Hari", 
         "friend" : "Shiva" 
          }, 
 "value" : { 
          "mutualFriend" :[ "Tom", "Karma", "Dinesh" ] 
           } 
 }
```

i have large number of document in MongoDB collection, containing `value.friendList` and `value.mutualFriend` and then i want to find only documents with `value.mutualFriend`

Comment: Use mongo `$in` for ref. check this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Comment: @Yogesh, i have tried `db.result.find({value:{$in:["mutualFriend"]}})`. but cannot get the result.

Comment: you tried wrong, try this `db.resul.find({"value.mutualFriend":{"$in":["Tom"]}})`.

Comment: i think i interpret my question  wrongly, here i want all document with `value.mutualFriend` and ignore document with `value.friendList`

Comment: This case you should use `$exists` like this `db.result.find({"value.mutualFriend":{"$exists":true}})` it will return only those document's having mutual friend key.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({"value.mutualFriend.0" : { $exists : true }})
```

Its just make sure that the 0th element exists. you can customize your query over various array length.